# What is the easiest way to migrate data from one Cosmos DB to another?

Tags: data-recovery, database, azure, data-migration

What is the easiest way to migrate data from one Cosmos DB to another?

I accidentally deleted all the databases in one Cosmos DB account. So, I asked the Azure support to restore the Cosmos DB account to a specific point in time (before the deletion happened). They satisfied my request by creating a new Cosmos DB account with all the data I need. But now there is a huge system which relies on the data being in the initial Cosmos DB account. So, I need to somehow copy the databases from one Cosmos DB account into another Cosmos DB account. Both accounts are situated on the same subscription.

The only solution I was able to find is using this [Azure TipsAndTricks](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip334.html) third party application. Given that I am a bit worried about the migrated data being leaked, I am not very eager to use a third party tool to do the migration. I would expect for there to be some Azure native solution to the problem, or at least something more reliable than the TipsAndTricks app.

Comment: Did you see this page as well? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/migration-choices